# To display distinct values and sum the values using sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the below code i have  a query and i want to display the values like this.I want to display distinct taxcalculation and it sum of total price based on unique taxcalculation.Pls help me to do this.

Invoice Detail Table:

TaxCalculation TotalPrice

```
 0.00            500
 0.00            750
 1.00            980
 2.00            400
```

Expected Result:

TaxCalculation TotalPrice

```
 0.00            1250
 1.00            980
 2.00            400



SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), I.CreatedOn, 105) AS InvoiceDate
    ,INVD.Interest
    ,CASE 
        WHEN Count(INVD.TaxCalculation) OVER (PARTITION BY INVD.TaxCalculation) > 1
            THEN SUM(Isnull((INVD.TotaPrice), 0.00))
        ELSE Isnull((INVD.TotaPrice), 0.00)
        END VATAMOUNT
    ,INVD.TaxCalculation
    ,INVD.TotaPrice
FROM Invoice I
LEFT OUTER JOIN Customer C 
    ON C.CustomerID = I.CustomerID
LEFT OUTER JOIN InvoiceDetail INVD 
    ON INVD.InvoiceID = I.InvoiceID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Locations L 
    ON L.LocationID = I.LocationID
LEFT OUTER JOIN LocationProductMap LPM 
    ON LPM.ProductID = INVD.ProductID
LEFT OUTER JOIN OrderForm O 
    ON O.OrderFormID = I.OrderFormID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Product P 
    ON P.ProductID = INVD.ProductID
LEFT OUTER JOIN UnitType U 
    ON U.UnitTypeID = P.UnitTypeID
WHERE I.InvoiceID = @i_InvoiceID
    AND LPM.LocationID = I.LocationID
GROUP BY I.TotalPrice
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), I.CreatedOn, 105)
    ,INVD.Interest
    ,INVD.TaxCalculation
    ,INVD.TotaPrice
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where I'd just use your query as a subquery

```
SELECT
    A.TaxCalculation 
  , SUM(A.TotaPrice) AS TotalPrice
FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT 
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), I.CreatedOn, 105) AS InvoiceDate
      , INVD.Interest
      , CASE 
          WHEN Count(INVD.TaxCalculation) OVER (PARTITION BY INVD.TaxCalculation) > 1
              THEN SUM(Isnull((INVD.TotaPrice), 0.00))
          ELSE Isnull((INVD.TotaPrice), 0.00)
          END VATAMOUNT
      , INVD.TaxCalculation
      , INVD.TotaPrice
  FROM Invoice I
  LEFT JOIN Customer C
      ON C.CustomerID = I.CustomerID
  LEFT JOIN InvoiceDetail INVD
      ON INVD.InvoiceID = I.InvoiceID
  LEFT JOIN Locations L
      ON L.LocationID = I.LocationID
  LEFT JOIN LocationProductMap LPM
      ON LPM.ProductID = INVD.ProductID
  LEFT JOIN OrderForm O
      ON O.OrderFormID = I.OrderFormID
  LEFT JOIN Product P
      ON P.ProductID = INVD.ProductID
  LEFT JOIN UnitType U
      ON U.UnitTypeID = P.UnitTypeID
  WHERE I.InvoiceID = @i_InvoiceID
      AND LPM.LocationID = I.LocationID
  GROUP BY I.TotalPrice
      , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), I.CreatedOn, 105)
      , INVD.Interest
      , INVD.TaxCalculation
      , INVD.TotaPrice
) AS A
GROUP BY A.TaxCalculation
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query gives the expected result.

select distinct tax,sum(price) from Invoice group by tax

Refer the below link for details:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/be9ae/2

If this is not the expected answer, let me know the data types of both tax calculation and total price defined.

Thank you.